# Can't read named parameter in controller CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.6

I'm trying to pass a named parameter to a function. It actually is passed through before `$this->request->is('post')`, but debugKit placed after this line returns `null`. What gives?

Route:

```
http://localhost/bake/users/login/ref:post
```

Controller:

```
public function login() {
    //it returns 'post' here successfully.
    debug($this->params['named']['ref']);
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        //it returns 'null' here.
        debug($this->params['named']['ref']);
    }
}
```

Comment: probably because you are posting to a different url without that in the url. Please tag the question with the version of CakePHP you are using and put e.g the output of `debug($_POST); debug($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])` in the question.

Comment: `debug($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])` returns `/bake/users/login` only. But there isn't such problem in all other controllers and functions.

Comment: `returns /bake/users/login` no ambiguity there - that's the url when you're debugging.

Answer (score 0):

I used sort of a pseudo method to go about it:

```
public function login() {
    //set the value to the view.
    $this->set('param', $this->params['named']['ref']);
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $param = $this->request->data['param'];
    }
}
```

In the view I added a hidden field:

```
<input type="hidden" name="data[param]" value="post"/>
```

So it gets the value with form is submitted.

Answer (score 0):

If you're lazy:

```
$this->request->query('ref')
```

If you're curious:

Documentation [here](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#query-string-parameters)

Source code [here](http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/source-class-Cake.Network.Request.html#1106-1116)

Comment: Can I suggest that you add further detail and/or reasoning behind your answer, code only answers might fix the explicit question it is answering however details on why etc. might allow someone reaching this from google (other search engines are available) to solve their own similar questions.

Comment: Done, although the answer I gave points exactly what/where to look at, it should take too long to open the API documentation and look for the method I suggested.